# pthread segmentation fault with linked lists - beginner

Tags: c, unix, pthreads

This is the first time I've used pthreads. I'm having trouble because some times my program seg faults and sometimes it does not. I have a few functions in my program that perform some basic tasks (written in C) like creating a linked list, adding an item to a list, and deleting an item from a list. Each function creates it's own copy of a list so I don't think they interact with each other and hence don't need mutexes. Anyway below is my code if anyone has any ideas or if there are any "common" beginner pthread mistakes.

I run each function 1000 times in parallel, some times seg faulting, some times not. I notice it only happens with a combination of these 3 functions.

The process goes like this:
- create thread
- run threads in parallel
- each thread calls dummy function to perform a task a given number of times
- that dummy function also calls other functions

I think it might have to do with memory usage/allocation because all of these functions have to do with creating/deleting linked list nodes. Thanks a lot.

Here are the creates and joins:

```
 pthread_create(&t7, NULL, (void*)&p4, (void*)var);
 pthread_create(&t8, NULL, (void*)&p5a, (void*)var);
 pthread_create(&t9, NULL, (void*)&p5b, (void*)var);
 pthread_join(t7, NULL);
 pthread_join(t8, NULL);
 pthread_join(t9, NULL);
```

Here are the dummy functions:

```
void p4(int *nptr){
  int n = *nptr;
  // Get current time
  struct timeval t0, t1;
  gettimeofday(&t0,0);

  int i = 0;
  LIST *list = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));
      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    f4(list);
    deleteList(list);
  }
  // Get current time and find time elapsed
  gettimeofday(&t1,0);
  float elapsed = (t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec;
      printf("Successful execution of p4 in %f microseconds.\n", elapsed);
  free(list);
}
void p5a(int *nptr){
  int n = *nptr;
  LIST *list = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));
  f4(list);
  // Get current time
  struct timeval t0, t1;
  gettimeofday(&t0,0);

  int i = 0;
      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    f5a(list);
  }
  // Get current time and find time elapsed
  gettimeofday(&t1,0);
  float elapsed = (t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec;
  printf("Successful execution of p5a in %f microseconds.\n", elapsed);
}
void p5b(int *nptr){
  int n = *nptr;
  LIST *list = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));
  f4(list);
  int i = 0;
      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    f5a(list);
  }
  // Get current time
  struct timeval t0, t1;
  gettimeofday(&t0,0);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    f5b(list);
  }
  // Get current time and find time elapsed
  gettimeofday(&t1,0);
  float elapsed = (t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec;
  printf("Successful execution of p5b in %f microseconds.\n", elapsed);
}
```

Here are the functions used that perform regular tasks:

```
// FUNCTION: initialize a linked list with pointers and insert a last element
void f4(LIST *L1){
  // initialize an empty linked list if L1 = null
  if(L1->head == NULL){
    NODE *n = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    L1->head = n;
    L1->tail = n;
    L1->tail->next = NULL;
    n->data = 1;
  }
  // traverse the linked list to the end
  NODE *iter = L1->head;
  while(iter->next != NULL)
    iter = iter->next;
  // insert a new 2 element
  NODE *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
  new->data = 2; // arbitrary for testing
  new->next = NULL;
  iter->next = new;
  L1->tail = new;
}

// FUNCTION: add an item to the end of a list (queue)
void f5a(LIST *list){
  NODE *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
  new->data = 999;
  new->next = NULL;
  list->tail->next = new;
  list->tail = new;
}

// FUNCTION: remove an item from the beginning of a list (queue)
void f5b(LIST *list){
  NODE *remove = list->head;
  list->head = list->head->next;
  free(remove);
}
```

Comment: I doubt the threads have anything to do with this. It doesn't seem like you're sharing any memory. I would look into testing your list functions better. (Also, jeebus, name them something descriptive!)

Comment: It may seem not important, but try not to use reserved keywords as variabe names: 'new' keyword is reserved in C++. I know that your program is in C, not in C++, but ... just in case avoid it. Maybe one day someone (e.g. you) will want to port it to C++ ...

Comment: Can you post deleteList code also?

Comment: What is 'var' which you are passing to the pthread_create? Is it a pointer? Also, what will be it's value and will it get updated in the main thread parallely. Better post full code as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read `malloc` man pages you can see that doesn't initialize allocated memory to 0. So, you `malloc` memory in `p4`, `p5a` and `p5b` functions. After this, you invoque `f4` function with no initialized LIST contens.

In `p4` function you check for a valid pointer with `if(L1->head == NULL)` but it maybe be not null. So you don't alloc memory for `L1->head` and, after this function, in `f5b` function you are freeing a non allocated pointer.

Advices:

- Always initialize allocated regions.
- Always check `malloc` returned pointers

Comment: Thank you for your insight. This was the problem. I initialized the head to NULL and all was forgiven.